# Как правильно отпозиционировать изображение на сайте?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, позиционирование

Задача, отобразить изображения вот так в мобильной версии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получается вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не понимаю почему. Не знаю как правильно сделать !

```css
.startImg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.startImg img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .startImg {
    height: 70vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-12 startImg">
      <img src="../img/aboutUsGirl.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не на то обращаете внимание  )

Comment: а зачем вы высоту меняете?

Comment: Она теряет форму так званого квадрата и становится маленькой по высоте и полностью занимает ширину. У меня в задаче сделать акцент на лицо в мобильной версии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы изображение не теряло свои пропорции при смене размера используйте [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

В вашем случае подойдёт `object-fit: cover;`

---

> ..в задаче сделать акцент на лицо..

Для этого используйте [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) и выставите значение на лице.

Answer (score 2):

чтобы картинки не плющило, используйте

```
height: auto;
```